# DC motor model issue

Tags: dc-motor, simulation, matlab, modeling

I use the following DC drive model:
[image: DC motor]

with the following parameters of the motor:
[image: Motor parameters]

Matlab variables for these parameters:

```
L = 0.343*10^(-3);                  % H
R = 11.4;                           % Ohm
Kt = 11.2*10^(-3);                  % Nm/A
Kemf = 1/(2*pi*849/60);             % 849 [rpm/V] -> [V/(Rad/s)]
J = 0.993*(10^-3)*(0.01)^2;         % [g * cm^2] -> [kg * m^2]
B = 0.00;                           % Friction coefficient
G = 35;                             % Gearing coefficient

Jload = 0.0;                       % N*m^2
```

Transfer function which converts torque into omega is derived from the following considerations(here I omit damping B):

[image]

What makes me feel that model does not work properly is its' output.
With `Jload = 0` I have the following current and speed responses:
[image]
[image]

And the settled speed actually is close enough to that of declared in `No load speed` field(note that field is in RPM while plot is in rad/s). However if I change `Jload` the behavior seems to be wrong. When I increase the load I expect that motor will shift along speed/torque curve leading to an increased current and reduced speed. Nevertheless making `Jload = 0.05` gives me the following output:
[image]
[image]

Here is how output is generated:
[image]

As you can see the only thing that changes is settling time. What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Missing some units ? Is RPM shown? Computed power/rated power? Or I ratios? Or actual RPM/torque curve

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 yep, sorry for that. Two plots:I(t) [A] and Omega(t) [rad/s].

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I have also revealed that motor link is broken so I have added screenshot with motor parameters from maxon web page.

Comment: Define ALL inputs and ALL outputs with units for graph.  I sense should not go to 0 for 12Vin, while  L/R ratio is one time constant and torque current with gear reduced speed G=35 and load inertia another T

Comment: G reduces RPM and increases output torque so define new W range.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I have updated graphs.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 `W` range actually does not matter right now. I use W without transmission because it will be used as a measurement source for a controller. What for the current I agree with you, though it should be relatively small (23.8 mA) according to datasheet, but it should not go to zero. However I have no ideas why it behaves this way.

Comment: DC motors are actually AC with commutation so I no load  I=V(/sLc+R) for some pole N* Rev/s*2pi=s. still don’t know input V nor how you computed I

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I posted the top level scheme at the end of the post. There you can see input and current measurement. I have also found out that for some reason back EMF became equal to input almost instantly as a result current tends to zero.

Comment: Why would inertia affect the steady state speed. It's a dynamic load in the motor. If you add friction you will have a steady state load.

Comment: Inertia only affects time constant, no load had internal inertia, extra load adds time until rated load is applied then time to reach rated power at ~10 to 15% slip speed depends on the f and sL inputs which is missing, ie the commutation frequency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\$J_{load}\$ is the moment of inertia of the load; mathematically it's the equivalent of mass in a system where you're dealing with linear motion.  Here's the details: $$T = J \alpha \\ F = m a$$ where \$T\$ is torque \$J\$ is moment of inertia, \$\alpha\$ is rotational acceleration (\$\ddot \theta\$), \$F\$ is force, \$m\$ is mass and \$a\$ is linear acceleration.

Increasing \$J_{load}\$ will slow the response of the system to changes in voltage, because it takes more torque to spin the motor up.  But \$J_{load}\$ does not change the amount of torque used by the system once it is at speed.  That is why when it eventually settles, it does so to it's previous speed and current.

This is *quite apparent in the math*, if you can pull your head out of dependence on Matlab for long enough to spend some time with a pencil and paper.  I highly recommend you do so; the equations of motion are first order and linear, so should be easy to solve.